# fopen() crashes the console

Tags: c, file

I'm relatively new to C and was working on a project to get a hang of it. I started to do a contact saving app, however, it crashes whenever I try to save the input data. The file exists, because it works on the first save made from the code, so the handler doesn't give an error, but something else does, which I can't get my head around. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Contact
{
    char Name[20];
    char Number[12];
};

int save(char* filename, struct Contact *conts, int n);
int load(char* filename);

struct Contact conts[] = {{"Jim", "123"}};
int amount = 0;

int main(void){

    char* filename = "D:\\NewCodes\\Metanit\\C\\Projects\\Phone Book\\Contacts.txt";

    //save(filename, conts, 1);

    char command;
    do{
        load(filename);
        printf("(N) Enter new contact \n");
        printf("(R) Remove contact \n");
        printf("(E) Edit contact \n");
        printf("(X) Exit \n");
        scanf("%c", &command);
        if(command == 'n'){
            system("cls");

            struct Contact nw = {"Name", "Number"};
            printf("\n Name ");
            scanf("%s", &nw.Name);
            printf("\n Number ");
            scanf("%s", &nw.Number);
            
            amount++;
            struct Contact tmpConts[(sizeof(conts))/sizeof(conts[0])];
            for(int i = 0; i < amount - 1; i++){
                tmpConts[i] = conts[i];
            }
            tmpConts[amount - 1] = nw;

            save(filename,tmpConts,amount);
        }else if(command == 'r'){

        }else if(command == 'e'){

        }else if(command = 'x'){

        }
        system("cls");
    }while (1);

    return 0;
}

int save(char* filename, struct Contact *conts, int n){
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;

    int size = n * sizeof(struct Contact);
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL){
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    c = (char *)&n;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++){
        putc(*c++, fp);
    }

    c = (char *)conts;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(size); i++){
        putc(*c++, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int load(char* filename){
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;

    int m = sizeof(int);

    int n, i;

    int *pti = (int *)malloc(m);

    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    int chk = fgetc(fp);
    if (chk == EOF) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        ungetc(chk, fp);
    }

    c = (char *)pti;
    while (m>0)
    {
        i = getc(fp);
        if(i == EOF) break;
        *c = i;
        c++;
        m--;
    }
    n = *pti;

    // Creating the contacts list
    struct Contact * contacts = (struct Contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct Contact) * n);
    c = (char *)contacts;
    while ((i = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        *c = i;
        c++;
    }

    printf("%d Stored in the file \n", n);
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        printf("%d \t %-20s \t %-12s \n", (k + 1), (contacts + k)->Name, (contacts + k)->Number);
    }

    conts[0] = *contacts;
    amount = n;

    free(pti);
    free(contacts);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I checked if the input was wrong, but the array got sent just fine. After that, I started to debug and got the message

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 2, save (filename=0x33323100000000 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x33323100000000>, conts=0x61fde0, n=2) at .\PhoneBook.c:71
71          if((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL){
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffe8f6c7a46 in msvcrt!_fsopen () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffe8f6c7a46 in msvcrt!_fsopen () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 15660.0x590 exited with code 3221225477]
[Thread 15660.0x179c exited with code 3221225477]
[Inferior 1 (process 15660) exited with code 030000000005]
(gdb)
```

Comment: How are you determining that it crashes there? Use a debugger and it will tell you the exact line that triggers the crash. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71623046/edit) the question to show the exact back trace of the crash.

Comment: Your `save` is returning a value, but you never check it.

Comment: Also there is no definition of `load`.

Comment: The `sizeof(size)` should be `size`? You probably only write 4 bytes of the `struct` array to file. So the first 4 bytes written to file (`n`) will mislead the `load` function.

Comment: When you allocate `tmpConts`, the number of elements is going to be constant since `conts` cannot change.  As soon as `amount` goes above 1 the behavior becomes non-deterministic.

Comment: The problem is that `conts` and `tmpConts` only have one element. But you're trying to access `amount` elements.

Comment: It's all unnecessarly complicated - consider using `fwrite` and `fread` to w/r whole objects.

Comment: `hit Breakpoint 1` Means it stopped at a breakpoint that you added. That doesn't tell us anything. You need to keep running the program until you see something that looks wrong or it crashes.

Comment: @Barmar I looked at what you wrote and it worked, but now the information gets jumbled up after I add more contacts and it only adds the fixed amount I wrote at the start. Is there any way of making that fixed amount dynamic?

Comment: You need to use dynamic allocation with `malloc()` rather than a static array.

Comment: @Barmar ok. I'll try that, but tomorrow. It's getting late here. Will write the results when I change the code.

Comment: Whatever you typed in ended with "321".  And corrupted the filename variable.  scanf() is a dangerous function and can easily cause a stack buffer overflow.  Get ahead by increasing the size of Name and Number, don't be modest.

Comment: I changed the array into with `malloc()` and it works now, but after inputting the new data, the old one gets corrupted and doesn't output. What should I look for in my code to resolve this?